# OSX Yosemite built-in Apache 403 ONLY on images

Tags: macos, permissions, apache-http-server

I have set up multiple local websites on my macbook (running Yosemite). All others are working fine. I am trying to do some work on a new one now and I've gotten everything running except for the images.

I have chmod'd all the image files to 755. The site runs fine as I can see content and navigation clicks around, etc. I can visit an .HTML file inside the images directory and it shows up. But if I try to view one of the image files using a web URL path it gives me a 403 forbidden error. I can view the image in a browser if I open it from finder, so I *think* it is not an issue of corrupt files.

I have run `ls -all` in terminal and can see that the permissions are identical between the HTML file that works and the images that don't.

Any ideas as to what is going on?